# How do I isolate Carousel slider from other pages that is not the home page in Blazor

Tags: html, asp.net, layout, components, blazor

I want to have a HTML structure that had Header, body, and footer and I want the navbar and carousel to be in the header section.

how do I make it so that when a user navigate to another page, while the navbar will appear in the other page I don't want the carousel to appear. how can I do this?

```html
  <header>
    <Navbar/> 
    <carousel/>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    @Body
  </div>
  <footer>
    This is the footer
  </footer>
```

Comment: "navigate to another page..." from where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the navigation manager and test for home uri condition.

```
<header>
    <Navbar/> 
@if (isHomePage)
{
    <carousel/>
}
</header>
<div class="content">
    @Body
</div>
<footer>
    This is the footer
</footer>

@code {
    [Inject]
    NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }

    bool isHomePage => Navigation.Uri == Navigation.BaseUri;
}
```

Comment: I did not think of to check using C# I was thinking towards structuring the HTML to do the job.